# Why is the movie The Equalizer named as such?

Tags: analysis, title, the-equalizer

I am wondering why *The Equalizer* was named as such.

In my opinion, the Equalizer is someone who makes things "equal", but what he does is more like a vigilante or a punisher.

Comment: Equalize justice for everyone, not only who can bend the laws, but for everyone specially innocent, incapable and in danger with combination of helping out to those who needed, make their lives normal again thus balancing the nature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The movies are spin-offs/remakes of an old TV show. 
The synopsis for the [original TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Equalizer) probably describes it better...

> The Equalizer is an American crime drama television series, originally airing on CBS from fall 1985 until late-spring 1989. It starred Edward Woodward as a retired intelligence agent with a mysterious past, who uses the skills from his former career to exact justice on behalf of innocent people who are trapped in dangerous circumstances. The series combined elements of the spy, private investigator/police procedural, and vigilante genres.

"exact justice on behalf of innocent people" 
is probably the salient part.

Comment: The original show was definitely more about righting of wrongs and restoration of normalcy, vs the much more graphic, vengeful and violent movie presentation.